# iphone Reachability issues

Tags: iphone, reachability

My app requires an internet connection, so in the ApplicationDelegate, on `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I am running the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];

hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
[hostReach startNotifer];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: hostReach];
```

But for some reason, this seems to be firing two times, since what gets logged is the following:

```
2010-02-04 14:25:48.004 myApp[201:207] Reachability Flag Status: -- ------- networkStatusForFlags
2010-02-04 14:25:48.240 myApp[201:207] STATUS: Access Not Available
2010-02-04 14:25:48.499 myApp[201:207] Reachability Flag Status: -- ------- networkStatusForFlags
2010-02-04 14:25:48.517 myApp[201:207] STATUS: Access Not Available
```

Which is good that it's working, but I have an alert message to notify the user that there is no connection, and it pops up twice...

Why is the reachability notifier firing two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why it's popping up twice. Have you tried commenting out the call to `startNotifier`? It might do an initial check in the `reachabilityWithHostName:` method.

This might be a case where a workaround is the most appropriate fix, e.g.:

```
static bool userNotifiedOfReachability = NO;

...

- (void)updateInterfaceWithReachability:(Reachbility *)reachability {
    if (!userNotifiedOfReachability) {
        // Notify User

        ...

        userNotifiedOfReachability = YES;
    }
}
```

That would be appropriate for a "please try launching the app again later" message.

Comment: That worked...almost. It's always the second time that confirms whether the connection is made, this is checking and ignoring the second time. I got it working though, thanks for the tip!